# Python equivalent of MATLAB command prod

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, porting

Is there a python equivalent of the MATLAB command "prod" (described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prod.html))?

Comment: The answer to this is better than the proposed duplicate because it references `numpy` which a user coming from MATLAB almost certainly is using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduce` in Python:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> reduce(mul, range(1, 5))
24
```

Or if you've numpy then it's better to use [numpy.prod](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10)
>>> a.prod()
362880
#Product along a axis
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)
>>> a.prod(axis=1)
array([  6, 120, 504])
```

Comment: Thanks!  The numpy suggestion works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in python, but you can get the product of all elements in a list, using `reduce` like this

```
myList = [1, 2, 3]
print reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, myList, 1)
```